# How to restrict the user to create High-end Ec2 machines and costly Resources in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I Have AWS Environment where we are giving a training session to students there we want to restrict the large type of Resources Launching like Ec2 and other AWS services.

Is there any IAM roles or any Policy Script in order to avoid unauthorized and cost-saving.

PLS advise.

Comment: maybe this blog could help: https://blog.vizuri.com/limiting-allowed-aws-instance-type-with-iam-policy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your IAM policies for your users you can add conditions on the particular instance types they can create; this won't be based on cost but you can specify exactly which types, see [the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#amazon-ec2-keys). You will put these in the [`Conditions` sections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html) of the IAM policy.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible using IAM [Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition.html), The sample policy given below explicitly deny creating High end ec2 instances

```
{
            "Sid": "limitedSize",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "*.nano",
                        "*.small",
                        "*.micro",
                        "*.medium"
                    ]
                }
            }
```